# Material-UI v5 override MuiSwitch input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to use `Switch` component from MUI v5 in a website with third party CSS that apply relative position to checkboxes and radios.

In v4 I was able to change this behaviour with an override:

```
overrides: {
  MuiSwitch: {
    input: { position: 'absolute !important' },
  } 
}
```

This was enough to set position to absolute.

Following the example provided by official documentation in order to migrate to v5 I changed the above snippet in:

```
components:{
    MuiSwitch: {
        styleOverrides: {
            input: {
                position: "absolute !important"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But `MuiSwitch-input` still has position relative.

Please take a look at this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicswitches-material-demo-forked-kvg5b?file=/demo.js).

The only solution I found was to put style in CSS:

```css
.MuiSwitch-input {
     position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with that code snippet of yours https://codesandbox.io/s/basicswitches-material-demo-forked-ui4lz?file=/demo.js

Comment: In your demo, if you add position relative to checkbox in a css file you can recreate the problem. I provided a demo with the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code didn't work, but I've found a workaround by specifying the switch input className directly like this:

```js
import Switch, { switchClasses } from "@mui/material/Switch";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          [`& .${switchClasses.input}`]: {
            position: "absolute"
          }
        },
        switchBase: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Seems like an issue with Switch component, not with my code.

Comment: @assistbss look like input style is applied to `SwitchBase`, not `input`  component, probably a bug from the framework

Comment: this is not necessary from v 5.0.2