# Mui v5 styleOverrides not working with themes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, themes

I am trying to style using theme overrides as laid out in the [documentation here](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides):

I have the following code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/globalthemeoverride-material-demo-forked-srvfc?file=/demo.tsx):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select'
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          background: '#000',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function GlobalThemeOverride() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            variant="standard"
          >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

The Select box should have a background of `#fff` however no background is set at all. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me (or at least missing a feature that is reasonable for developers to expect to be there). The issue is that Select doesn't define any styles of its own at the root level, so it doesn't leverage the code (which would be a call to MUI's `styled` such as [here for the `select` class](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.4/packages/mui-material/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L24)) that would take care of looking at the theme and applying the corresponding style overrides. I recommend logging an issue.

There are a couple possible workarounds.

#### Workaround 1 - Target the `select` CSS class

This approach may work, but it depends on what all you are trying to do since this targets a child of the root element.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      styleOverrides: {
        select: {
          backgroundColor: "#000",
          color: "#fff"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit GlobalThemeOverride Material Demo (forked)]

#### Workaround 2 - Target the `MuiInput-root` CSS class

The approach below targets the same element as `MuiSelect-root` by leveraging `MuiInput-root` (the rendering of the root element of the Select is [delegated to the `Input` component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.4/packages/mui-material/src/Select/Select.js#L68) when the variant is "standard") and then qualifying it via `"&.MuiSelect-root"` so that it only affects `Select` rather than all inputs.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&.MuiSelect-root": {
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            color: "#fff"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit GlobalThemeOverride Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: putting the styles directly in `root` works for [me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmhVS.png) in approach #2.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Yes, but it will affect all standard `Input` elements, not just `Select` elements.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/globalthemeoverride-material-demo-forked-qbtuq?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I'm too tired to look at it now, but maybe it is also related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69280433/9449426).

Comment: Ahhh interesting, so you can still refer to things as `MuiXxx`. This single fact has confused me allot. Do you use `"& .xxx"` or do you use `select` as suggested in the documentation. But I see, the key is actually to use the cascading idea and go levels above and come back down.... Very good to know, I appreciate it.

Comment: @JamieHutber The `Muixx` name is a convention, some components like `Box` doesn't have it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69455458/9449426) answer if you want to apply the styles from `createTheme` in your custom component. See this typescript [file](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/styles/components.d.ts) for a list of all supported components.

Comment: Interestingly, I tried with `root` and it failed. I needed the `select` part again! :O